# Graph in SAS coming up with strange values using gchart function

Tags: graph, sas

I am trying to create a graph from a table I've made. I want to graph the values for month with the numbers in the Scheduled column. Unfortunately, it is displaying the months as like .75 or 2.25 and 4.75 instead of the actual month numbers and I don't know why.

I have tried changing the type of graph, the sumvar, the axes and values for them, but none of this has helped... it worked at one point but then simply stopped and I cannot figure out why.

```
1   SKED    7573
1   UNSK    1882
2   SKED    6635
2   UNSK    1642
3   SKED    817
3   UNSK    208
4   SKED    9494
4   UNSK    2376
5   SKED    1900
5   UNSK    551
6   SKED    9864
6   UNSK    3319
7   SKED    9770
7   UNSK    4145
```

```
pattern1 value=solid color=CXc01933;
pattern2 value=solid color=CX003366;
axis1 label=(angle=90 'Amount of Wheelchair Requests');
axis2 label=('Month') order=(0 to 12 by 1);

proc gchart data=Overall_Arr;
    vbar month / type=sum SUMVAR=Arr_num subgroup=scheduled raxis=axis1 maxis=axis2 
    autoref clipref ;
run;
```

This is the table and this is the code to make the graph. I am expecting an output of a graph with two different colored bars, signifying the scheduled number and the unscheduled number. Before I put the order on the second axis it would output a graph but would have strange numbers for the month, like .75 or 4.25, etc, instead of using the 1 2 3 etc to signify the months. Now it is outputting no bars, I am assuming because it is trying to use those weird numbers but I've restricted the axis to whole numbers for the month... Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Doyou have to use SAS/GRAPH? It's pretty outdated and SGPLOT would be much easier.

Comment: Has to be in sas, I'll take a look into SGPLOT , thanks!

Comment: axis options in SG have a type, specify time and SAS will know to keep the axis as a date/time format with appropriate labeling.

Comment: please add column headers to your data and a sceeenshot of your result.

Answer (score 0):

Alright I actually think I figured it out, the problem was that month is also a command, so changing my variable's name allowed for it to be a variable instead of a command.